# How do I get public feed from facebook without user authentication on a native/Desktop app?

Tags: facebook, c#-4.0, facebook-authentication, facebook-sdk-3.0

I'm looking to get publicly available facebook feeds (i.e. [Google's facebook page/posts](https://www.facebook.com/Google)).  However I want to be able to access these feeds without having the user log into the application.

I've looked into using "[App Access Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/)" however since my application is a "native/Desktop" app (iOS, Android, WP8/Win 8) I'm not able to do this.  Is there a way to get publicly accessible feeds from facebook **without** user authentication?

I'm using the Facebook C# SDK to access the facebook API's.  Here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
    dynamic tokenInfo = fb.Get(
        String.Format(
            "/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&grant_type=client_credentials",
            FbController.AppId,
            FbController.AppSecret));

    var appAccessToken = (string) tokenInfo.access_token;

    fb = new FacebookClient();
    dynamic response = fb.Get(
        String.Format(
        "/google/posts?access_token={0}",
        appAccessToken));
```

The problem is that this only works if my application is set to a "web" app instead of "native/Desktop".  I get the following error when running this code and classified app as native/Desktop.

> (OAuthException - #1) The request is invalid because the app is configured as a desktop app

Comment: Hey did you get a solution to this, if yes please share it with us. I'm stuck on at somewhat similar dilemma.

Comment: I am having the same issue? Let me know if you got any solution for this.